# Retrying a request based on response body in Node JS

Tags: node.js, http, request

I am using Node JS to forward some requests to retrieve data from a backend system. Sometimes I want to retry a request after validating some values from the response body (in my case an error in the response body that says 500 status)

I've been reading about streams and pipes etc but still have no clue how to handle it properly. Any ideas appreciated.

```
function callBackend(req, res, accessToken, next) {
  var backendRequest = backendOptions.getRequest(req, accessToken); //helper function that will populate HTTP.request options

  var clientReq = backendRequest(); //new request to call backend

  if (url.destination.timeout) {
    clientReq.setTimeout(url.destination.timeout);
  }
  clientReq.on('timeout', function () {
    clientReq.abort();
    //... handle timeouts
  });
  clientReq.on('error', function (err) {
     //... handle errors
    }
  });

  req.pipe(clientReq); //pipe original request to backend request

  clientReq.on('response', function(clientRes) {
    var requests = {
      incomingRequest: req,
      incomingResponse: res,
      outgoingRequest: clientReq,
      outgoingResponse: clientRes
    };

    onResponse(requests, requestStats, next);

  });
}
```

Here is the onResponse function that will handle the backend response

```
function onResponse(requests, requestStats, next) {
  var incomingRequest = requests.incomingRequest;
  var incomingResponse = requests.incomingResponse;
  var outgoingRequest = requests.outgoingRequest; //backend
  var outgoingResponse = requests.outgoingResponse; //backend

  incomingResponse.statusCode = outgoingResponse.statusCode;
  incomingResponse.statusMessage = outgoingResponse.statusMessage;

  outgoingResponse.on('timeout', function() {
    outgoingRequest.abort();
    //... handle timeouts
  });
  outgoingResponse.on('error', function(err) {
    //... handle errors
  });

  incomingResponse.on('error', function(err) {
    //... handle errors
  });

  //outgoingResponse.pipe(incomingResponse);

  streamToString(outgoingResponse, (data) => {
    if (data.includes('HTTP/1.1 500')) {
         //this works fine. response body includes a 500 error, i want to retry the request. how do I retry the request?
    } else {
       //response body is ok, do I simply write to incoming response?
       incomingResponse.write(data);
    }
  });
}

function streamToString(stream, cb) {
    const chunks = [];
    stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
        chunks.push(chunk.toString());
    });
    stream.on('end', () => {
        cb(chunks.join(''));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retry a failing request multiple times, you should put the request making logic in a separate function and call it as you want.

```
function makeRequest(req, res, accessToken, next, nAttempts) {

  var backendRequest = backendOptions.getRequest(req, accessToken); //helper function that will populate HTTP.request options

  var clientReq = backendRequest(); //new request to call backend

  if (url.destination.timeout) {
    clientReq.setTimeout(url.destination.timeout);
  }
  clientReq.on('timeout', function () {
    clientReq.abort();
    //... handle timeouts
  });
  clientReq.on('error', function (err) {
     //... handle errors
    }
  });


  /* Write the request instead of piping  - because we need to retry*/  
  clientReq.write(req.body);  
 //req.pipe(clientReq); //pipe original request to backend request

  clientReq.on('response', function(clientRes) {
    var requests = {
      incomingRequest: req,
      incomingResponse: res,
      outgoingRequest: clientReq,
      outgoingResponse: clientRes
    };

    onResponse(requests, requestStats, next, nAttempts, accessToken);




}
```

Get your route handler to call this function initially

```
function callBackend(req, res, accessToken, next) {

    makeRequest(req, res, accessToken, next, 0)
}
```

And, call the same function if it fails

```
if (data.includes('HTTP/1.1 500')) {

     if (nAttempts !== maxAttempts)
        makeRequest(incomingRequest, incomingResponse, accessToken, next, nAttempts++ )

}
```

Comment: Currently I am piping the request like so `req.pipe(clientReq); //pipe original request to backend request`. Reading the documentation wouldn't this cause the original request to end at the end of the stream? Are there any alternative way so I can use the original request for the retries?

Comment: Yes! you are corret, You cannot use pipe if you want to retry. Please see the update.

Comment: Sorry - the update was not saved. Please see now. use body-parser to have the raw request in the req.body

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're moving to a wrong direction. I'd recommend you to simplify your code down to this:

```js
const axios = require("axios")

async function callBackend(req, res, accessToken, next) {

...

  const { data, status } = await axios("http://example.com", {method: "POST"});
  if (status === 500) {
    // try again
    const { data, status } = await axios("http://example.com", {method: "POST"});
  }
}
```

This way the code would be much shorter and easier to read.

That would be a proper way of handling.

Comment: the status from my response is in the body but i suppose axios returns the body in (data)? i asked in my other comments but was wondering how i can re-use a original request to retry multiple times. currently i pipe the request directly which i think ends it at the end of the stream

Comment: To do the same request you'd need to pass exactly the same variables to the "axios()" function.